# Fetching database records with MySQL - random row selection with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm trying o fetch data from a database specific to a quiz. I have two tables named 'questions' and 'options'. Each question has 2 corresponding options and 'questionID' row is present in 'options' table as a foreign key.
I'm fetching 4 random questions and their corresponding answers with this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM questions INNER JOIN options ON
    questions.questionID=options.questionID, (SELECT questionID AS sid FROM questions 
    ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 4 ) tmp WHERE questions.questionID = tmp.sid AND
options.questionID=questions.questionID ORDER BY questions.questionID
```

This query runs fine and retrieves appropriate rows from both questions and options tables on phpMyAdmin but when I fetch the array in php and then retrieve the arrays with AJAX all the options are random and not matching with their questions - some of them do not match with any of the questions selected.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

I checked the php fiel on its own and it seems like it's only the AJAX's fault. Now I see why - I'm making two calls to the file and I think it might be running the query again and that's why the answers do not match. Any solution?

Here's my AJAX call the same is for answers just with different url parameter:

```
var dataQuest = (function() {  
    var questions;
    function load(){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: "randomQ.php?q=0",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                questions = data;
                //alert(questions);
                alert(questions);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('#place1').text("Error: " +textStatus +" "+ errorThrown);
            }
        });//end ajax
    } //end of load
    return {
        load: function() { 
            if(questions) return;
            load();
        },
        getQuest: function(){
             if(!questions) load();

             return questions;
        }
    }
})();//end of dataQuest function
```

As requested - the php bit:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
            $quests[] = $row['question'];
            $answers[] = $row['option'];
}

//$questions = array_unique($quests);
//$answs = array_chunk($answers, 2);

if($_GET['q']==0)
{
    echo json_encode($quests);

}
else
{
    echo json_encode($answers);
}
```

I've changed that into:

```
$arrays[] = $quests;
$arrays[] = $answers;


    echo json_encode($arrays);
    //echo json_encode($answers);
```

And that returns the appropriate answers and questions to AJAX - however to make that work - I need to split this 2D array in Javascript - any recommendations on how to achieve that appreciated.

Comment: can you share your JS/AJAX code ?

Comment: Can you show your PHP process in randomQ.php?

Comment: The results you fetched are in JSON format? I mean the one generated in and sent by randomQ.php

Comment: @MikeMiller updated the question - it must be that on second call for answers - the query is running again

Comment: Can you dump out `$stmt->fetchAll()`?

Comment: @MikeMiller yup, it's dumping each column - questions and answers related - so in the end 8 rows  - duplicate questions with corresponding answers

Comment: See my edit below. Instead of using arbitrary incremental index (eg an empty key `[ ]=$value`) use something you have that is unique ie the primary key of the question. Then loop your result into an array using either of approaches below and everything will be inherently related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN options ON
questions.questionID=options.questionID
WHERE options.questionID=questions.questionID 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8 //You will need 8 rows as each question has 2 option rows
```

Hard to know without seeing your db schema but this should work.

In your PHP script this change may help you associate the data in your jQuery:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
        ///use the PK of the question instead of arbitrary index
        $quests[$row['question_id']] = $row['question'];
        $answers[$row['question_id']] = $row['option'];
}
```

Or maybe..

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
        //create a single array indexed by question pk with sub array of options
        $quests[$row['question_id']]['question'] = $row['question'];
        $quests[$row['question_id']]['options'][] = $row['option'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this query does not work as it doesn't recognize tmp.sid. I checked the php and it's fetching appropriate columns/fields. It's the AJAX code problem - I've updated my question.

Comment: Yeah sorry you shouldnt need that condition. You dont show how you are returning the info back from PHP but I cant see how the Ajax code would mess your data up. You might be having a problem with json_encode (if you are using it) not maintaining the keys in a none associative array

Comment: Thank you!!! The second option works like magic and now I only need one AJAX call. Awesome :)

Comment: Have you changed that if statement at the end of the PHP? It might be returning the empty/none existent `$answers` array maybe?

Comment: It alerts [object Object]

Comment: Thats a good thing. Thats your JSON object you will need to access the index you want eg `alert(questions.question)`

Comment: Ok, I'll figure the rest out then - thanks a lot for help! :)

Comment: No problems. You will probably need to look at jQuery each() function for looping the options out